# rank based on counts (hiveql)

Tags: hive, count, hql, hiveql, window-functions

I want to rank conversation ids by their count of occurrences, so the first occurance is ranked as 1, second is ranked as 2, third is 3 etc.

I am getting a syntax error so most likely something is off

```
select 
    conversationid, 
    rank() over (partition by conversationid order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from my_table
  group by conversationid
```

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: line 7:54 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'count'

Comment: Which error do you get exactly? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64232989/edit) to include this important piece of information. Also, sample data and desired results would help understanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: just updated thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rank conversations by their count, then you don't want a `partition by` clause in the window function:

```
select conversationid, rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rnk
from mytable
group by conversationid
```

This assigns rank `1` to the most frequent conversation(s).